# Perform an action after trigger('click') finishes firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I manage a SharePoint site and have limited access to the underlying code; I can, however, manipulate things after the page loads via JavaScript.  Have been using jQuery and SPServices.

I have a custom button I am adding to a form; it overrides the standard "save" button on the page, so I can perform some other ajax stuff prior to saving/closing.  This works fine:

```
$('#the_save_button').hide();

$("#my_custom_save_button").click(function() {
    // do some custom stuff first
    $('#the_save_button').trigger('click'); // 
    window.close();
}
```

The item saves and the `window.close()` fires.  Great!  Now, though, I would rather not close the window but set the `window.location.href` ... however, when I do that, the page is getting redirected *before* the `trigger('click')` is finished firing and my item isn't saving:

```
$('#the_save_button').hide();

$("#my_custom_save_button").click(function() {
    // do some custom stuff first
    $('#the_save_button').trigger('click'); // 
    window.location.href = "/my/new/url.aspx";
}
```

I've tried using `window.setTimout` but the `$('#the_save_button').trigger('click')` has a built-in redirect itself ...

Any ideas on how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just have your click handler return a deferred object and use it to decide when to redirect.

```
$("#the_save_button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return $.ajax({...});
});
```

Now you can do this:

```
$("#my_custom_save_button").click(function() {
    // do some custom stuff first
    $('#the_save_button').triggerHandler('click').done(function(){
        window.location.href = "/my/new/url.aspx";
    });

});
```

Note: using `triggerHandler` instead of `trigger` in this case is important, `triggerHandler` allows you to use the returned `jqXHR` object.

Comment: You might have to hold my hand a little: this makes sense for me up to the `return $.ajax({...});` What is the `{...}` I am returning?  Something obviously belongs there but I don't know what.  Smile.

Comment: That's just your ajax request. For example, `$.post(url,handler)` or `$.get(url,handler)` or `$.ajax({url: url, success: handler})` Whatever you are already using.

Comment: From what I read online, it looks like `preventDefault()` does what it says ... but I need the default action to fire; I don't want to suppress it entirely.  I can't actually re-create what it's doing because of how it's hard coded in there ... I need to like delay my own location.href as long as the `window.close()` was delaying it.

Comment: you can just remove that line then, it was there to replace `return false` if you were using it.