# action after trigger click fired

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I already checked out this post:
[Perform an action after trigger('click') finishes firing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15417180/4685497)
But nothing I tried so far worked.

Suppose I have this menu in my page:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li role="presentation" id="home">
                <span>
                    Home
                </span>
            </li>

            <li role="presentation" id="user">
                <span>
                    User
                </span>
            </li>
 </ul>
```

When I click "user" tab, I get this content:

```
<button id="save-changes" role="button">Save it</button>
<form>
     <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Your Name">
     <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Your Surname">
     <input type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Your Login">
</form>
```

After submitting data, I'm redirected to "Home":

```
   <div>
        <div class="breadcrumb">
            <div id="saved-success" style="display:none">
                 Data Saved successfully
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-body">
             some stuff here...
        </div>
```

I want the message inside the div "saved-success" to appear.
To manage the submit I have this jquery function:

```
 $(document).on("click","#save-changes",function(){
     dataarray = array(
        login: $("#login").val();
        nom: $("#nom").val();
        prenom: $("#prenom").val();
     );
     $.post(getBaseUrl(true)+"/UserParam/saveUser",dataarray,function(){
        $("#home").trigger("click");
        $("#saved-success").css("display", "block");
    });
```

I am successfully redirected to "home" but the div "saved-success" remain hidden. Need help from experts. How do I make the message to show after redirection?

Comment: Are you sure you are executing your Javascript after "saved-success" has been rendered in the DOM? Also your button id is "save-changes" and not "save-change" that you have in your "click" listener.

Comment: Use query string for sending specific data to redirected page

Comment: Are you making a pageload after `$("#home").trigger("click");` has been triggered so the whole page reloads?

Comment: you can use $(document).find("#saved-success").css("display", "block"); if not displaying.. then console the element like console.log( $("#saved-success")); in ajax success

Comment: @Strahdvonzar - Thank you, I corrected it

Comment: @spoq - There's no page reload in the trigger, thanks :)

Comment: @JananiKumar - I did as you told me but it didn't work and console.log returns "undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click","#save-change",function(){
 dataarray = array(
    login: $("#login").val();
    nom: $("#nom").val();
    prenom: $("#prenom").val();
 );
 $.post(getBaseUrl(true)+"/UserParam/saveUser",dataarray,function(){
    $("#home").trigger("click");
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("updated-success").style.display = "block";
    }},2000);
});
```

Comment: This could work if clicking home does not generate a page load.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! the 'setTimeout' has made it!